# framework or tips for making a webpage for researchers to edit and publish papers

Tags: web-applications, web

Right now I am making a website for a team of researchers to edit their paper, comments on other people's paper, and publish the paper when it's ready

I am wondering if there are any frameworks out there to make it easier to build, or what languages to use for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Some friend told me to look into drupal, and I was also thinking about to use a Twiki...  I haven't really started yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend simple things like Sinatra (Ruby) or Node.js (Javascript).

There are many pre-built gems/modules that help deal with things like users, databases, etc.